# How to implement SearchView (ActionBarSherlock) using android annotations?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-annotations

I successfully implemented search view with action bar sherlock but just for curiosity, how can I do that using Android Annotations?

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    SearchView searchView = new
            SearchView(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
    searchView.setQueryHint(getString(R.string.hint_search_bar));
    menu.add("Search")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.icon_search)
            .setActionView(searchView)
            .setShowAsAction(
                    MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM
                            | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);

    return true;
}
```

I created a xml menu and annotate my Activity with

```
@OptionsMenu(R.menu.menu_search)
```

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menuSearch"
    android:actionViewClass="SearchView"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_search"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    android:title="@string/lbl_search">
</item>
```

but the search icon click doesn't open the search text field. I think the problem is this line

```
SearchView searchView = new
            SearchView(getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext());
```

that cannot be reproduced in xml. Am I right?

Comment: Did you get a chance to look and try my answer?

Comment: Oh thank you @tasomaniac but I'm not on this project anymore so I haven't tested it. It will probably work, though. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

When you do like below, I think it should work.

```
<item
android:id="@+id/menuSearch"
android:actionViewClass="com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView"
android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
android:title="@string/lbl_search">
</item>
```